# GitHub Actions - "Node.js 12 actions are deprecated." although I upgraded everything to v18

Tags: node.js, github-actions

I get the warning

```
Node.js 12 actions are deprecated. 
For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-22-github-actions-all-actions-will-begin-running-on-node16-instead-of-node12/. 
Please update the following actions to use Node.js 16: ./
```

I know it's because v12 has been deprecated and is being removed, but I've changed my usages from v12 to v18 and I don't understand why I still get this warning. It should have vanished.

I've read the doc for Actions Maintainers at https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runs-for-javascript-actions

- I only specify a nodejs version there: https://github.com/UnlyEd/github-action-await-vercel/blob/main/.github/workflows/update-codeclimate-coverage.yml#L24
- I use "@actions/core": "1.10.0"

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While writing the question, I noticed in https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runs-for-javascript-actions that there was a `runs:`. I had seen it, and overlooked it.

I didn't understood it was located in the `/action.yml`, at the root.

Here is an example: https://github.com/UnlyEd/github-action-await-vercel/blob/cee5b33a0725899c2a78be7d73819114f6aac745/action.yml#L17

Changing this line obviously fixed the issue.

Answer (score 11):

I faced this issue when deploying a NextJS application using GitHub actions.

My job looked like this:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

The issue was with the `actions/checkout@v2` which had be deprecated. All I had to do was to upgrade to `actions/checkout@v3`. So my job looked like this next:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

**Resources**: [Example: Using versioned actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-versioned-actions)

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue in my Next.js project.

I could resolve this issue by setting node-version as 16 in the GitHub workflow/*.yml file.
For example:

```
jobs:
  bulid:
    name: Production
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 16
```

Answer (score 1):

Was facing this issue in my workflow which used below actions to perform upload artifacts

```
- name: Setup Java
  uses: actions/setup-java@v2
```

GitHub actions execution was finishing with below error.

```
The following actions uses node12 which is deprecated and will be forced to run on node16: actions/setup-java@v2.
```

**Solution**: Try the updated version of github action

```
- name: Setup Java
  uses: actions/setup-java@v4
```

And the warning is gone.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I'm afraid this question has many answers, as it's really related to which actions are being used, and all of them must be updated for the warning to go.