# Update your actions to run on Node 16 instead of Node 12 on GitHub

Tags: node.js, github-actions

While I've seen it claimed that this question was answered elsewhere, it was not.  I am getting a complaint about using Node 12 instead of Node 16 in this code:

There is no documentation that says exactly what is the difference between Node 12 and Node 16 (at least not in the provided links.)  The

```
  lint-flake8:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: flake8
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.8]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python ${{matrix.python-version}}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: ${{matrix.python-version}}
    - name: flake8
      continue-on-error: false
      run: |
        pip install flake8
        flake8 pyuvm tests/pytests
```

The supposed answer on StackExchange ([GitHub Actions - "Node.js 12 actions are deprecated." although I upgraded everything to v18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75061837/github-actions-node-js-12-actions-are-deprecated-although-i-upgraded-everyt)) says something about `run` vs `runs`.

Do I just change the word `run` to `runs` in the last command?

Comment: The warning messages don't mention the action name in your case? Looks like `actions/checkout@v2` should be `actions/checkout@v3` and `actions/setup-python@v2` should be `actions/setup-python@v4`. See https://github.com/actions/checkout and https://github.com/actions/setup-python. Regarding deprecation, see https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-22-github-actions-all-actions-will-begin-running-on-node16-instead-of-node12/.

Comment: Regarding [`run`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun) vs [`runs`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runs), you don't need to change `run` to `runs`. You are writing a GHA workflow and not a GHA action.

Answer (score 6):

You probably need to upgrade the actions to the latest version:

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- uses: actions/setup-python@v4
```

Both now have a much newer version.

The easiest way to stay current is to enable Dependabot for GitHub Actions.

[image: Enable dependency updates]

Then add a file to your repo to enable dependabot (`/.github/dependabot.yml`) for actions:

```yaml
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "github-actions"
    directory: "/" 
    schedule:
      interval: "weekly"
```

You then get updates that keep you up to date automatically:

[image: PR for actions]

Comment: If Dependabot isn't your thing, renovatebot also has these features.

Answer (score 1):

Was getting similar warning for multiple github actions.

My workflow was using below actions

```
  - name: Upload artifacts
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2

  - name: Checkout code
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

and

```
- name: Upload artifacts
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
```

And warning of pattern below was being raised by GitHub. As you can see below one is highlighting warning for **checkout** and **upload** actions

```
Node.js 16 actions are deprecated. Please update the following actions to use Node.js 20: actions/checkout@v3, actions/upload-artifact@v3
```

**Solution**
Use the upgraded version of the actions. So I went for latest.

```
  - name: Upload artifacts
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4

  - name: Checkout code
    uses: actions/checkout@v4

- name: Upload artifacts
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
```

And that sorted the problem.